# Getting running config for kube master components from active cluster

Tags: kubernetes, controller

We have a kube cluster with 5 masters and 50 worker nodes. The kube cluster is running on bare-metal server, not as containers. During the cluster initialization, we update the parameters for the kube-api-server/scheduler/controller as required for our environment, but not all options. 
Like for a node, we can get the current applied kubelet configs using the API - :/api/v1/nodes//proxy/configz, is there a way to get the current configs (like kube-api-qps, kube-api-burst etc) for the master components (controller, scheduler).

I could get the metrics and healthz for controller and scheduler on 10252 and 10251. However, I could not find how to get the current config for these components via an API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not from the API (As of this writing) Typically the component configs are passed in through the [command line](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/#kube-apiserver) or/and a Pod YAML manifest file. Typically, the manifest files are under `/etc/kubernetes/manifests`

- kube-apisever -> `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`
- kube-controller-manager -> `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`
- kube-scheduler -> `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml`

For example, minikube `kube-apiserver`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    component: kube-apiserver
    tier: control-plane
  name: kube-apiserver
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-apiserver
    - --advertise-address=192.168.64.6
    - --allow-privileged=true
    - --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC
    - --client-ca-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/ca.crt
    - --enable-admission-plugins=NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,DefaultStorageClass,DefaultTolerationSeconds,NodeRestriction,MutatingAdmissionWebhook,ValidatingAdmissionWebhook,ResourceQuota
    - --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true
    - --etcd-cafile=/var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/ca.crt
    - --etcd-certfile=/var/lib/minikube/certs/apiserver-etcd-client.crt
    - --etcd-keyfile=/var/lib/minikube/certs/apiserver-etcd-client.key
    - --etcd-servers=https://127.0.0.1:2379
    - --insecure-port=0
    - --kubelet-client-certificate=/var/lib/minikube/certs/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt
    - --kubelet-client-key=/var/lib/minikube/certs/apiserver-kubelet-client.key
    - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
    ...
```

The kube-proxy is a bit different.

- kube-proxy -> kube-proxy ConfigMap YAML in the kube-system namespace

To get a sense of what you can do with the API you can use the `kubectl get --raw` command. For example:

```
$ kubectl get --raw /
{
  "paths": [
    "/api",
    "/api/v1",
    "/apis",
    "/apis/",
    "/apis/admissionregistration.k8s.io",
    "/apis/admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io",
    "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/apiregistration.k8s.io",
    "/apis/apiregistration.k8s.io/v1",
    ...
```

Comment: An e.g of how we start the api server is as below, though I have not included all the options that we set here. If these are not propogated to etcd, then I think there is no way to get the current values in a running cluster. As I said we dont use manifest files to start the master components. e.g to start the api-server 


/usr/bin/kube-apiserver --secure-port=443--alsologtostderr=true --service-cluster-ip-range=<ip>/24    --client-ca-file=<path to file> --tls-cert-file=<path to file> --tls-private-key-file=<path to file> --allow-privileged=true --service-account-key-file=<path to file>

Comment: That's correct. The state of all those options are not persisted into etcd and are rather in mem variables. I think the fact that you can query the node is a nice to have.

Answer (score 0):

The control plane resource files will be stored on /etc/kubernetes/manifests directory. You can look at the configuration of those components from there.

Or You can run below command to get the output from running pods.

```
   kubectl -n kube-system get <pod name> -o yaml
```

Comment: We are  starting the kube-controller/scheduler/api-server from the command line with the options that we update as per our environment. We dont use the yaml file for this. We pass the client certs,ca, audit path etc etc as arguments from the command line. What we were looking at is, there is a set of params other than that we have modified and is there is away to check what is the value of all those params in the scheduler/controller. Since we dont run these master components as containers, there is no pod in kube-system name-space.